# How to get the number of rows and SUM of the fields after grouping them in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, count, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an XML that contains workers and amounts. In the output, the file will contain lines for a worker - one line if he has EX  and one line if he has ER. He has EX if he has amount1 in the xml file, and ER if he has amount2. This works perfectly fine in the my current XSLT. 
The main issue is on how to properly get the correct total number of rows and the sum of all amounts (both amount1 and amount2) after grouping them, and should be added in the header. 
Here's the sample XML:

```
<Report_Data>
<Report_Entry>
    <Worker>
        <Name>User1</Name>            
        <ID>1234</ID>
    </Worker>
    <amount1>-200</amount1>
    <amount2>100</amount2> 
</Report_Entry>    
<Report_Entry>
    <Worker>
        <Name>User1</Name>           
        <ID>1234</ID>
    </Worker>
    <amount1>100</amount1>
    <amount2>-50</amount2> 
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Worker>
        <Name>User2</Name>            
        <ID>5678</ID>
    </Worker>
    <amount1>-20</amount1>  
    <amount2>100</amount2>         
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Worker>
        <Name>User1</Name>            
        <ID>1234</ID>
    </Worker>
    <amount1>0</amount1>
    <amount2>0</amount2> 
</Report_Entry>  
</Report_Data>
```

Here's my sample XSLT (im working on the counter but cant get it right. Tried a lot but I ended up having the count in the variable here but it's getting all the rows instead of 3. i think its because of the current-group looking all the row values on the xml...) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:ns0="urn:com.foo" extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>


<xsl:variable name="SumOfAmount1" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="SumOfAmount2" saxon:assignable="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="countEX" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Data/Report_Entry" group-by="Worker/ID">

        <saxon:assign name="SumOfAmount1" select="sum(current-group()/Report_Data/Report_Entry/amount1)"/>            
        <xsl:if test="$SumOfAmount1 >= 0.00">
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"></xsl:sequence>

        </xsl:if>     

    </xsl:for-each-group>          
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="countER" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry" group-by="ID">

        <saxon:assign name="SumOfAmount1" select="sum(current-group()/Report_Data/Report_Entry/amount2)"/>            
        <xsl:if test="$SumOfAmount1 >= 0.00">
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"></xsl:sequence>                
        </xsl:if>     

    </xsl:for-each-group>          
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report_Data">        

    <Header>
        <!--Total count of rows!-->
         //add countER and countEX
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <!--Sum of amount1 and amount2 !-->
        //add total amounts 

    </Header>
    <ReportData>

        <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="Worker/ID">
            <ReportEntry>                                            
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/*[starts-with(name(), 'ID')]"/>
            </ReportEntry>

            <saxon:assign name="SumOfAmount1" select="sum(current-group()/amount1)"/>
            <saxon:assign name="SumOfAmount2" select="sum(current-group()/amount2)"/>


            <xsl:if test="$SumOfAmount1 >= 0.00">
                <xsl:call-template name="EX"></xsl:call-template>                    
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$SumOfAmount2 >= 0.00">                                       
                <xsl:call-template name="ER"></xsl:call-template>                                                               
            </xsl:if>                                   

        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </ReportData>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="EX">              
    <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Name"/>
    </Name>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="Worker/ID"/>
    </ID>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>        
    <amount1>            
        <xsl:value-of select="$SumOfAmount1"/>            
    </amount1>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>                                                       
    <xsl:value-of select="'EX'"></xsl:value-of>        
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xa;'"></xsl:value-of>            
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ER">         
    <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Name"/>
    </Name>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="Worker/ID"/>
    </ID>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>        
    <amount1>            
        <xsl:value-of select="$SumOfAmount2"/>            
    </amount1>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>                                                       
    <xsl:value-of select="'ER'"></xsl:value-of>        
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xa;'"></xsl:value-of>                                                                                            
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output:

```
 2,150
 User1,1234,50,ER
 User2,5678,100,ER
```

where: 2 is the number of rows and 150 is the sum of all the amounts (amount1 and amount2).

P.S. negative amounts are not included in the file. if amount1 or amount2 are negative, they are still included in the addition but if the sum amounts to negative, it will be excluded and not displayed in the file.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group once by the ID and then store the row data based on whether there are the `amount1/amount2` elements. To compute the sum I would simply select the elements again:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="rows" as="element(row)*">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Data/Report_Entry" group-by="Worker/ID">
             <xsl:if test="current-group()/amount1">
                 <row>
                     <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Name, current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/amount1), 'EX'" separator=","/>
                 </row>
             </xsl:if>
             <xsl:if test="current-group()/amount2">
                 <row>
                     <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Name, current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/amount2), 'ER'" separator=","/>
                 </row>
             </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="count($rows), sum(Report_Data/Report_Entry/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'amount')]), $rows" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpA

It seems I did not quite get the format right, see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpA/1 for the correction which uses

```
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(count($rows), ',', sum(Report_Data/Report_Entry/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'amount')])), $rows" separator="&#10;"/>
```

For the refined requirement to eliminate groups with summed amounts being negative I think that

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="rows" as="element(row)*">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Data/Report_Entry" group-by="Worker/ID">
             <xsl:variable name="sum1" select="sum(current-group()/amount1)"/>
             <xsl:if test="current-group()/amount1 and $sum1 > 0">
                 <row sum="{$sum1}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Name, current-grouping-key(), $sum1, 'EX'" separator=","/>
                 </row>
             </xsl:if>
             <xsl:variable name="sum2" select="sum(current-group()/amount2)"/>
             <xsl:if test="current-group()/amount2 and $sum2 > 0">
                 <row sum="{$sum2}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="Worker/Name, current-grouping-key(), $sum2, 'ER'" separator=","/>
                 </row>
             </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(count($rows), ',', sum($rows/@sum)), $rows" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

does that: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpA/2

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks. I updated my question and added about the negative amounts that should not be included in the file. its in the PS section. :) im trying your suggestion. im struggling with the header with your code here..i'd like to ask how can I make the count and the overall sum in one line, and process records in the newline (like the exact expected output i mentioned in my question?) thank you.

Comment: You can adjust the `value-of` to `<xsl:value-of select="concat(count($rows), ',', sum(Report_Data/Report_Entry/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'amount')])), $rows" separator="&#10;"/>` to put the count and the sum in the same line. I am afraid your post scriptum talking about negative amounts is not sufficient to tell us how your data can look and which result you want, either edit your question and show sample input and result data or ask a new question with those details.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks. I've updated the sample XML and the expected output to reflect about what I mean on the negatives.

Comment: sorry, just updated the xml and output again. amount1 for user1 has a total now of -100, so since this is negative, this should not be included in the file as a row. the count in the expected output returns to 2.

Comment: Well, the expected output shows `2,150` and the text trying to explain that tells us "2 is the number of rows and 500 is the sum of all the amounts". That does not look like a consistent specification to me.

Comment: got me there,. sorry :) should be 150 in the example. (the sum of all the amounts in the rows displayed in the output.)

Comment: I have added a third sample which stores the summed amounts greater than zero in an attribute and outputs the sum of those attribute values.